# Org-Mode Custom Agenda View: Show Status Of All Current Habits

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use `org-habit` to keep track of some of my recurring tasks in org-mode.

By default the habits show up in my agenda view (along with their progress graph) if they are scheduled for the current day. Once I mark a habit task as done, it disappears from the agenda view.

Sometimes I want to see how I'm doing with my all my habits. What I want to see is an agenda view that shows *all* tasks that are habits (along with their progress graph) and *only* those tasks (i.e. tasks that aren't habits should be excluded).

How do I construct such an agenda view?

I know I can use `org-habit-show-habits-only-for-today` to show all habits in the agenda, even if they aren't scheduled today. However, I can't figure out how to *exclude* those tasks that *aren't* habits.

Answer (score 1):

An item is a habit if and only if the `STYLE` property is set to `habit`.  You can search for this using the built-in agenda search (`C-c a s`) and searching for `STYLE="habit"`.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude non-habits from daily agenda view you can set `org-agenda-skip-function` variable in your custom agenda view definition (`org-agenda-custom-commands`) as:

```lisp
(org-agenda-skip-function
 (lambda ()
   (unless (string-equal (org-entry-get (point) "style") "habit")
     (outline-next-heading))))
```